# stringi::stri_unescape_unicode() for longer / rarer unicode characters?

Tags: r, stringi

We see `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode()` works for the first two unicode characters, but seemingly not the third

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

c("\\uFFE6", "\\u1ECB0", "\\u11FE0") %>%  stringi::stri_unescape_unicode()
# [1] "￦"      "ị0"      "\u11fe0"
```

Is there a way to `stringi::stri_unescape_unicode()` for longer/rarer unicode characters? (or is it actually unescaping correctly and I'm not seeing it because of some local settings, e.g. fonts not installed?)

Comment: I've posted a new question related to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74495452